# How could I make this python code execute faster?

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, cluster-computing

I scraped data from the web and am inserting it into a db inside a cluster. There's 4,771 documents in it and it takes so long to run that it is executing while I write this. Here's the code:

```
cols = [i for i in ncaabb_player_pg_df.columns]
db.drop_collection('player_pg')
for i in ncaabb_player_pg_df.index:
    data = {}
    for k in cols:
        data = {}
        data[k] = ncaabb_player_pg_df.to_dict()[k][i]
    db.player_pg.insert_one(data)
```

Note:
The _id is the player's name and I do not want to change the schema

Comment: You should determine where the time is spent. Comment out the `insert_one()` call. Does it complete quickly? If yes, then you're going to have to investigate what you can do to improve the performance of ingestion into MongoDB, for example by batching insertions using `insert_many()` or reviewing the configuration of your cluster.

Comment: Calling `ncaabb_player_pg_df.to_dict()` inside the loop is probably super expensive for a large df... At the very least, call it only once outside and store that in a variable. (Not the only problem with this code, but hopefully this will get you unblocked.)

Comment: I noticed that you are recreating `data` for each column in the innermost loop. Is that what you want? wouldn't that limit the data being inserted into the db to the last column only?

Comment: thanks Branden, that cut the execution time for each key, value in half. I used time package to log it.

Comment: You're right Josh, didn't realize I did that.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate all your comments.

This code will do.

```
cols = [i for i in ncaabb_player_pg_df.columns]
db.drop_collection('player_pg')
Dict = ncaabb_player_pg_df.to_dict()

for i in ncaabb_player_pg_df.index:
    data = {}
    for k in cols:
        data[k] = Dict[k][i]
    db.player_pg.insert_one(data)
```